# Translating interface of TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

Options language in tab navigation doesn't change.

I use it:
[tinymce-rails-langs](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails-langs)

In `_form.html.haml`, where I use tinymce add:

```
    = f.text_area :content, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 40, :cols => 120
    ...
    ...

    :javascript
      tinyMCE.init({
        selector: 'textarea.content'
        language: 'pl'
      });
```

Where is problem, why doesn't it change language?

Comment: Did you download the PL language pack from the TinyMCE web site?  Without that the `language: 'pl'` setting won't work.

Comment: @MichaelFromin I add gem tinymce-rails-langs, where pl.js is included. What I should more do?

Comment: When the editor loads does it try to load that JS file?  Do you see that in the browser's network traffic?